# How do I get a default picture when a picture errors

Tags: php, image, src

I am trying to get a picture from the database and echo this on my website, and everything works like I want to, but now I got this tiny problem where if the image has no name yet, or it errors (like a 404 error), that I get a ugly tiny broken image icon.

Can I get it to work that I get a default image when I get the error? I tried this, but it only worked for where there was no name set yet.

```
if(!empty($filename)){ echo $filename;} else{ echo "pf.png"; }
```

Comment: You can't just echo that, if you want the image to show as an image; you use `<img src="xxx.xxx">`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ofcourse I know that, this is only the part where I show the default image...

Comment: See Clément's answer then. I'd say that's what you need.

Comment: You'll need to post more code then and examples of your data, if Clément's answer did not work. My blind guess would be to check/query if the row is empty, assign a default image; otherwise, pull it from DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this in the image tag:

```html
onerror="this.src='[img src]'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you say it is working with "pf.png", I assume that you are at least using the filename correctly. So if you get that broken image, it means the resource could not be loaded, because it does not exist or cannot be retrieved.

So you also have to check that the image exists before trying to use it anyhow :

```
if(!empty($filename) && file_exists($filename) { 
  echo $filename;
} else { 
  echo "pf.png"; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. It removes all images and replaces it with the default one :(

Comment: @JeramaiFaber Probably because `$filename` is just the last part of a path, right ?  I guess you have something like : <img src="/url/images/**$filename**"> ? If so, add the path before the filename : `file_exists('path/path/' . $filename)`

Comment: @JeramaiFaber Had you posted more code related to how you were using `<img src>`, this would have most likely been solved within 30 seconds; if not 10.

Comment: @JeramaiFaber In a way you were and in another you weren't. The latter being not having shown us "how" you were using `<img src>` in the first place. But Clément did in fact come through as the "code detective" and pinpointed why it wasn't working for you. A tap on his shoulder, wouldn't you agree? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To do this i php, you will have to check if the file exists. You wont be able to do this if the link to the image is over "http:/www.*"

Clément Malet code above works fine.

You can read more about file_exitsts function here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

If the link to image is over "http:/www.*" you can use jquery. 
Put this code before `</body>` Remember to include jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").error(function(){
       $(this).attr("src", "http://google.dk/default.php");     
   })
   .each(function() {
       $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src")); 
   });
})
```